# Can't push code to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

```
git push heroku master

Using rails (3.2.13)
   Installing rdiscount (2.0.7.2)
   Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
   /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
   checking for random()... yes
   checking for srandom()... yes
   checking for rand()... yes
   checking for srand()... yes
   checking size of unsigned long... long
   checking size of unsigned int... int
   no int with size 4
   *** extconf.rb failed ***
   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
   necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
   details.  You may need configuration options.
   Provided configuration options:
   --with-opt-dir
   --without-opt-dir
   --with-opt-include
   --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
   --with-opt-lib
   --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
   --with-make-prog
   --without-make-prog
   --srcdir=.
   --curdir
   --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
   --with-rdiscount-dir
   --without-rdiscount-dir
   --with-rdiscount-include
   --without-rdiscount-include=${rdiscount-dir}/include
   --with-rdiscount-lib
   --without-rdiscount-lib=${rdiscount-dir}/lib
   Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_cnp5x6n0104p/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rdiscount-2.0.7.2 for inspection.
   Results logged to /tmp/build_cnp5x6n0104p/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rdiscount-2.0.7.2/ext/gem_make.out
   An error occurred while installing rdiscount (2.0.7.2), and Bundler cannot
   continue.
   Make sure that `gem install rdiscount -v '2.0.7.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

!
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'
gem 'google-webfonts'
gem 'postmarkdown'
gem 'rdiscount', "~> 2.0.7.2"

group :development, :test do 
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :test do 
gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end

group :production do 
gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

I seemed to start to have problems after I added the postmarkdown gem. I also ran `gem install rdiscount -v '2.0.7.2' in the command line but I'm still receiving this error. Thanks for any help or let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 1):

you can add `ruby "1.9.3"` in your gemfile like

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "1.9.3"
```

and then again `bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ruby version to Gem file

```
source :rubygems
ruby "1.9.3"

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'
gem 'google-webfonts'
gem 'postmarkdown'
gem 'rdiscount', "~> 2.0.7.2"
....
```

ruby 1.9.2 seems to have problem with heroku